# How can I run a system command and die if anything is written to STDERR?

Tags: perl, system, stderr, die

I'm writing a Perl script which uses an external script. The external script must run from a specific directory so I found the following useful:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture);

my @args = ('external script path...', 'arg1', ...);
my $out = capture( [0], "cd $dir ; @args" );
```

Sometimes the external script writes stuff to STDERR but still returns 0. I wish to capture these times and `confess` (or `die`). Since I don't control the return value of the external script, I thought maybe I could capture its STDERR so I'll have something like this:

```
my ($out, $err) = cool_capture( [0], "cd $dir ; @args" );
say "Output was: $out";
if ($err) {
 die "Error: this was written to STDERR: $err";
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [covered](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3F) in the Perl FAQ.

Presuming `test_app` is a program that outputs one line to stdout and one line to stderr:

```
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol 'gensym';

my($wtr, $rdr, $err);
$err = gensym;

my $pid = open3($wtr, $rdr, $err, 'test_app');

waitpid($pid, 0);
my $status = $? >> 8;

my $stdout = <$rdr>;
my $stderr = <$err>;

print "out output: $stdout\n";
print "err output: $stderr\n";

print "Exit code: $status\n";
```

EDIT: Per the request updated to include capturing the exit code. You could also have asked `perldoc IPC::Open3` which says

```
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
```

And which you should read anyway for its cautions and caveats.

Comment: +1 for giving both the reference in the Perl doc, and providing the answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Can you extend this to verify the return value of `test_app` is valid (e.g. `0`, as in `capture( [0], ...)`)?

Comment: How does this change if your presumption that `test_app` only outputs one line to stdout and one line to stderr? what would change if it outputs more lines?

Comment: The answer lies in the line `my $stdout = <$rdr>;` This only captures the first line from the file handle. If there are more lines you would want to capture more lines. For simplicity I did not bother.

Answer (score 1):

If significant output is being written to stdout and/or stderr or you're both reading and writing to the process. You need to be a lot more careful with your I/O handling to avoid various blocking problems.

```
my ($wtr, $rdr, $err) ;

my $pid = IPC::Open3::open3($wtr, $rdr, $err, @_);

close($wtr);

my $stdout = '';
my $stderr = '';

my $s = IO::Select->new;

$s->add($rdr) if $rdr;
$s->add($err) if $err;

while (my @ready = $s->can_read) {

    foreach my $ioh (@ready) {

        my $bytes_read = sysread($ioh, my $chunk = '', 1024);

        die "read error: $!" unless $bytes_read >= 0;

        if ($bytes_read) {
           ($ioh eq $rdr? $stdout: $stderr) .= $chunk;
        }
    else {
            $s->remove($ioh);
        }
    }
} 

my $pid1;
for (;;) {

    last if kill(0, $pid);

    $pid1 = wait();
    #
    # Wait until we see the process or -1 (no active processes);
    #
    last if ($pid1 == $pid || $pid1 <= 0);
}
```

Finish reading before you shutdown the process. If you're writing to the process's stdin, you'd also need to add $wtr and syswrite to the above select loop.

**EDIT**

Rationale:

The above is probably overkill for simple cases. This advanced handling of input and output comes into play when you're likely to move more than a few K of data.

You wouldn't need it if you were executing a 'df' command for example.

However, it's when system buffers for any of stdin, stdout or stderr fill up that blocking becomes likely and things can get more involved.

If the child process fills up the stderr and/or stdout buffers, it'll likely block and wait for you to clear them. But if you're waiting for the process finish before you read from stdout or stderr; thats a deadlock. You'll likely to see that the system call never finishes and the child process never completes.

There's a similar possibility of deadlock if stdin is being written to, but the child process is unable to consume the input. This is particularly likely in a 'pipe' situation where the child process is consuming input and writing to stdout.

The select loop is about progressively clearing the buffers to avoid blocking. Both stdout and stderr are monitored concurrently.

If you're writing to stdin and reading from stdout (a pipe), you'll want to keep stdout and stderr clear and only write to stdin when its ready to receive input.

Simply waiting for the process to finish, then reading stdout/stderr probably works 90% of the time. This reply is just to give you somewhere to go if things get more complicated and processes start to block or go into deadlock.

**EDIT2**

As for which to use, I'd say start simple, test hard.

Go with Sorpigal's approach, but try to stress test with higher data volumes and under more difficult loads and conditionals that you'd ever expect in a live system.

Comment: Can you explain why all of this is needed?

Comment: @David B: I've added some explanation. Hope this helps.