# Die if anything is written to STDERR?

Tags: perl

How can I force **Perl** script to die if anything is written to STDERR ?

Such action should be done instantly, when such output happen, or even before, to prevent that output...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run a system command and die if anything is written to STDERR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377967/how-can-i-run-a-system-command-and-die-if-anything-is-written-to-stderr)

Comment: @sputnick - No system command involved...

Comment: written to stderr by what?  (i.e., do you mean to include other processes started by your process? C library code called by your perl code? perl warnings?  explicit prints to stderr?)

Comment: @ysth - Anything, so incl., but not limited to all what you mentioned...

Comment: `use warnings FATAL => 'all'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a method that works no matter how STDERR (fd 2) is written to, even if it's a C extension that doesn't use Perl's `STDERR` variable to do so. It will even kill child processes that write to STDERR!

```
{
   pipe(my $r, my $w)
      or die("Can't create pipe: $!\n");
   open(STDERR, '>&', $w)
      or die("Can't dup pipe: $!\n");
   close($r);
}

print "abc\n";
print "def\n";
print STDERR "xxx\n";
print "ghi\n";
print "jkl\n";
```

```
$ perl a.pl
abc
def

$ echo $?
141
```

Doesn't work on Windows. Doesn't work if you add a SIGPIPE handler.

Comment: Interesting! If I want to add some functionality before quit, how would I need to modify your code, please? Also, would it work together with "die handler" `$SIG{__DIE__} = \&__die__;` ?

Comment: Nope, it's not dying. It's killed by the OS. $SIG{PIPE} will catch it.

Comment: And how can I add some functionality (callback function) to your code before it is killed?

Comment: $SIG{PIPE} will catch it.

Comment: I am confused now... In your answer you wrote *"Doesn't work if you add a SIGPIPE handler"*.

Comment: Different questions have different answers. In the original question, you asked for the program to end. Having a SIGPIPE handler would prevent the program from ending, which would be bad. But now you want to do something in response to the event rather than dying. Having a SIGPIPE handler would prevent the program from ending, which would be good.

Comment: So if I add `exit;` into SIGPIPE handler, I can add some functionality in such event and actually let program to end, correct?

Comment: What if technically something wrong happen inside of SIGPIPE handler? Would it end, or it may lead into catastrophic recursive loop..?

Comment: I interpreted the answer to my comment to mean that the *parent* should die if a child (or grandchild, etc) writes to that STDERR; other than that, nice answer

Comment: Re: "What if technically something wrong happen inside of SIGPIPE handler?" Try it and see. (The signal will get queued.)

Comment: @ysth, I hadn't seen your comment. Obviously, having the child die is not intentional, and $SIG{PIPE} won't catch those. (You can probably prevent the child from dying by using `$SIG{PIPE}='IGNORE';` post-`fork` and pre-`exec`.)

Comment: @ysth, If children are involved, the best way would be to wrap the process, giving it a pipe for STDERR, and send TERM to the process group if anything is received on the pipe. SIGTERM could be caught if any cleanup needs to be performed.

Answer (score 14):

This doesn't seem like an especially smart idea, but a tied filehandle should work. According to the [`perltie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html#Tying-FileHandles) manpage:

> When STDERR is tied, its PRINT method will be called to issue warnings and error messages. This feature is temporarily disabled during the call, which means you can use warn() inside PRINT without starting a recursive loop.

So something like this (adapted from the manpage example) ought to work:

```
package FatalHandle;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub TIEHANDLE {  my $i; bless \$i, shift }

sub PRINT { 
    my $r = shift; 
    die "message to STDERR: ", @_;
}

package main;

tie *STDERR, "FatalHandle";

warn "this should be fatal.";

print "Should never get here.";
```

And that outputs (with exit code 255):

```
message to STDERR: this should be fatal. at fh.pl line 17.
```